# WordPress MetaBox not showing on submenu page

Tags: php, wordpress

Menu and i try to show the metabox on it . I try everything thing but couldn't successed . I search on google and follow the same code but the result is disappointing.
Submenu page code is below:

```
add_submenu_page( 'mymenu', 'First Submenu', 'First-Submenu', 'manage_options','first-submenu', 'metaFunction' )
```

and metaFunction is below:

```
function metaFunction() {
    add_meta_box('post-reference', 'Reference', 'referenceCallBack', 'first-submenu');
}
```

Comment: If you are creating a menu for a custom plugin then you cannot add meta boxes to that page.. because meta boxes are for default or custom post types in WordPress. Instead create a html form.

Comment: You can, however, use the settings api.

Comment: @PrakashRao You should submit your comment as the answer here. I'd upvote it!

Comment: @PrakashRao sorry folk you are wrong . You can add meta-box on any custom page but the approach is different at this time .. Here is the tutorial link which i used and successfully added meta-box on my custom page

[Integrating With WordPress’ UI: Meta Boxes on Custom Pages](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-meta-boxes-on-custom-pages--wp-26843)

Answer (score 0):

@ Baerkins here you go :

If you are creating a menu for a custom plugin then you cannot add meta boxes to that page.. because meta boxes are for default or custom post types in WordPress. Instead create a html form

@Burhan Nasir : Yes you can do so , but still what they are doing is creating their custom form and assigning the metaboxes to them. Its coded manually whereas the WordPress provides metaboxes directly to default post types. If it worked then great , but it can also be done by creating a simple form and saving that to database atleast would have reduced the hooks and all. :)